# How to get the radius of an editable circle Google Map Api V3 on the fly? is it possible?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, overlay

```
 var sunCircle = {
    strokeColor: "#c3fc49",
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: "#c3fc49",
    fillOpacity: 0.35,
    map: map,
    center: userPosition,
    radius: 1000, // in meters
    editable:true
};
cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle(sunCircle);
cityCircle.bindTo('center', marker, 'position');
```

Now its Editable is true we can edit the circle, can i get the radius if user changes the radius?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
google.maps.event.addListener(cityCircle, 'radius_changed', function () {
    console.log(cityCircle.getRadius());
});
```

You can find more info about editing events [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#user_editable_shapes_events)

Answer (score 0):

In React we can use ref

STEP 1: Import useRef from react library

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
```

STEP 2: create refCircle variable inside react component

```
let refCircle = useRef(null);
```

STEP 3: create handleCircleRadius inside react component

```
const handleCircleRadius = () => {
  console.log('New Radius', refCircle.getRadius());
};
```

STEP 4: use ref and handleCircleRadius method inside the circle component

```
<Circle
  ref={(ref) => (refCircle = ref)}
  defaultCenter={{
    lat: parseFloat(12),
    lng: parseFloat(12),
  }}
  defaultEditable={true}
  radius={parseFloat(1000)}
  center={{
    lat: parseFloat(12,
    lng: parseFloat(12),
  }}
  onRadiusChanged={handleCircleRadius}
  options={{ strokeColor: '#ff0000' }}
/>
```

NOTE: this circle method import from `react-google-maps` library

Library Link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-maps
[image]

**OutPut**
[image]